# How To Sum Numbers With Commas In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have string field like (1100,2014,4000) i want to separate comma and sum every number with each other for instance:
1100,2014,4000

```
1 1 0 0
2 0 1 4 
4 0 0 0
```

result

```
@first =1+2+4=7 
@second= 1+0+0=1
@third=0+1+0=1
@forth=0+4+0=4
```

Comment: Write a function which can return the sum of every number.

Comment: Why would you want to store your data like this?

Comment: how does your table looks like ? `1100,2014,4000` is one single string or 3 separate rows

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: And this is t'he reason because Dr. Codd let us the first normal form.

Comment: @Mureinik i working in database and that field fill like this

Comment: @Squirrel in one single string

Comment: @mostafaasadollahy Check my Answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @DineshDB your answer very helpful but i want to use it as a function 
and face with error do you know have can it function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Value VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('1100,2014,4000')

 DECLARE @First INT, @Second INT, @Third INT, @Fourth INT

SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
INTO #temp
FROM  
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Value  
    FROM  @Table
) AS A CROSS APPLY Value.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a); 


SELECT @First=SUM(Data/1000)
    ,@Second=SUM((Data%1000)/100)
    ,@Third=SUM((Data%100)/10)
    ,@Fourth=SUM((Data%10))
FROM #temp

SELECT @First, @Second, @Third, @Fourth

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help to get sum of values like this :

```
SELECT  SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(X.A, 1, 1) AS INT)) first,
    SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(X.A, 2, 1) AS INT)) second,
    SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(X.A, 3, 1) AS INT)) third,
    SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(X.A, 4, 1) AS INT)) fourth
FROM    ( SELECT    '1100' A
      UNION
      SELECT    '2014' A
      UNION
      SELECT    '4000' A
    ) X
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Select statement with multiple SQL CTE expressions can be used with the help of a [numbers table function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx) and a [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) for splitting numbers list using "," as seperator

For further splitting each number into its numerals, I preferred to use substring function

```
with cte as (
    select
    *
    from NumbersList n,
    dbo.NumbersTable(1,4,1) as nt 
), splitted as (
select
    list,
    id,
    i,
    substring(val,i,1) val
from cte
cross apply dbo.Split(list,',') v
)
select
    distinct
    list,
    i,
    sum(cast(val as int)) over (partition by list, i) sumOf
from splitted
```

The output for following entries

```
insert into NumbersList select '1100,2014,4000'
insert into NumbersList select '1111,2222,3456'
```

is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This, firstly, uses Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (as I don't know what version of SQl Server you're on). Secondly, your logic seems a little off. You say that the value for your variable `@third` is `0+4+0`, however, that's the 4th characters of the ints. Also, this **assumes** that all integers are 4 characters long.

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('1100,2014,4000')) v(DSn)) --This is your samnple data 
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0000' + DS.Item,4),N.I, 1))) AS [Sum]
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (VTE.DSn,',') DS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) N(I)
GROUP BY N.I;
```

Comment: i miss that @third = 1 , @forth=4
thanks for your answer
and yes all of them have 4 character

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function for all item to row in a table.

you can create this function and try then 
select * from dbo.string2table('1243,1234,2343',',')

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[string2table]
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(
    data VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)

    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @end = 0 
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (data) 
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))
        SET @start = @end + 1
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END

    RETURN

END
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using a `CURSOR`. They are inherently slow.

Comment: Ok Larnu, I agree with you, especially i dont use cursor awaid of deadlocks, but this function is written already, I asked to solve for this question. Thanks.